# Raise .NET event from one DLL to another in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, event-handling, c++-cli

I have a native C++ application and two dll written in C#. Let's says that the native C++ application is 'AnApp' and the two dll are 'RaiseEvent'.dll and 'HandleEvent'.dll
Each of the two C# dll contains a class. RaiseEvent launch an event and HandleEvent subscribe to this event in order to execute a method called 'ReceiveEvent'.

In AnApp, there is a C++/CLI class that serves as a wrapper.
In this wrapper, I instantiate an object from RaiseEvent and another from HandleEvent.
Then, the event is launched (I can see it in the debugger). I was expecting the event to be handled in the HandleEvent class, but it didn't happens. I mean, it never enter in the ReceiveEvent method.

I made all of this as a proof of concept, I was not sure that it was supposed to work.

So, the question is, is it possible to handle an event from one .NET dll to another when each dll are used in a native C++ application through a C++/CLI wrapper?

Comment: That should be pretty common code, so you'll need to show what you did so we can see where it went wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its difficult to understand your exact problem without seeing some sample code, but I'll have a go.

Instantiating the objects is not enough to link the event to the event handler.
The event must be subscribed via the `+=` operator

```
var raiseEvent = new RaiseEvent();
var handleEvent = new HandleEvent();
raiseEvent.TheEvent += handleEvent.ReceiveEvent;
```

I wouldn't recommend publicly exposing `ReceiveEvent` function like this.
But the `HandleEvent` object needs access to the `TheEvent` instance in order to subscribe it.

Maybe something like:

```
class HandleEvent
{
    //...

    public void Subscribe(RaiseEvent eventRaiser)
    {
        eventRaiser.TheEvent += this.ReceiveEvent;
    }
}

//...

var raiseEvent = new RaiseEvent();
var handleEvent = new HandleEvent();
handleEvent.Subscribe(raiseEvent);
```

Comment: Your answer lead me to find why it didn't work. The problem is that I was instantiate a raiseEvent object in the wrapper class. Then, I was instantiating another raiseEvent objet in the handleEvent class in order to subscribe to the event. But, the way it was implemented, the event was fired in the first objet, so the one in raiseEvent never fired its own and never was handled in the raiseEvent class.
Finally, it was a design problem at first when I want to build this proof of concept.
Anyway, thanks to all and you for having take your time to help me.